# erro ao chamar um método passando uma classe como parâmetro c#

Tags: c#

Boas!

Eu peguei parte de um código que cria um usuário no AD com C#, o problema é quando vou chamar o método, eu sou iniciante em programação, vou passar o código e o erro.

```
  private static DirectoryResponse EnviarRequisicaoLdap(DirectoryRequest request)
    {
        LdapConnection ldapConexao = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(LdapServidor, LdapPorta));
        try
        {
            // Tipo de autenticação com o LDAP
            ldapConexao.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
            // Envia as credenciais com o dn completo
            NetworkCredential credenciais = new NetworkCredential(LdapUsuario, LdapSenha);
            // Estabele a conexão com o LDAP
            ldapConexao.Bind(credenciais);
            // Envia a requisição ao LDAP
            return ldapConexao.SendRequest(request);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Libera a conexão com o LDAP.
            if (ldapConexao != null)
                ldapConexao.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public static bool IncluirUsuario(Usuario usuario)
    {
        if (usuario != null)
        {
            string dn = string.Format("uid={0},{1}", usuario.Email, LdapUnidadeOrganizacional);

            AddRequest addRequest = new AddRequest(dn);

            addRequest.Attributes.AddRange(new DirectoryAttributeCollection() {
        new DirectoryAttribute("objectClass", LdapObjectClass),
        new DirectoryAttribute("uid", usuario.Email),
        new DirectoryAttribute("cn", usuario.Nome),
        new DirectoryAttribute("sn", usuario.Sobrenome),
        new DirectoryAttribute("userPassword", ConverterSenhaLdapMD5(usuario.Senha)),
    });

            // Acessando o LDAP
            EnviarRequisicaoLdap(addRequest);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IncluirUsuario();
    }  
o parametro está em branco, pq qualquer coisa que eu passar, vai dar erro.
```

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter "usuario"

Desde já agradeço.

---

@G.OtaniP nao entendi muito bem, como disse sou iniciante, mas vou postar a classe aqui e obrigado pela reposta:

```
public sealed class Usuario
    {
        public string Nome = "TESTE";
        public string Sobrenome = "CJ";
        public string Email = "teste@alpha.com";
        public string Senha = "******";
    }
```

Comment: O parâmetro que você precisa passar é um objeto do tipo `Usuario`. Veja a declaração dessa classe `Usuário` e como você pode instanciar e preencher ele antes de chamar a função `IncluirUsuario()`

Comment: Cara acho que descobri com a dica que você me deu! consegui instanciar.

Comment: Anderson, se você conseguiu resolver seu dúvida, peço que a marque a questão como resolvido, abaixo dos upvotos nas respostas. Valeu.

Answer (score 2):

O erro se dá por que você a função `IncluirUsuario(Usuario usuario)` requer um parâmetro. Esse parâmetro deve ser um objeto do tipo `Usuario`, ou seja, você vai ter que instanciar essa classe `Usuario` e mandar essa instância (objeto) como parâmetro da função.

Se a classe `Usuario` for essa que você mostrou na sua [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/372590/140938), você tem que instanciar ela que nem você [fez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/372591/140938):

```csharp
Usuario exemplo = new Usuario();
```

Porém, além disso, a função `IncluirUsuario(Usuario usuario)` parece resgatar e usar os atributos (`Nome`, `Sobrenome`, etc) do objeto `Usuario` que você passou como parâmetro, então é bom você preenchê-los antes de enviar ele para a função:

```csharp
// Em algum lugar do código, você vai alterar os atributos do exemplo (resgatando de um TextBox por exemplo)
exemplo.Nome = "Exemplo"
exemplo.Sobrenome = "De Código"
exemplo.Email = "exemplo@decodigo.com"
exemplo.Senha = "senhaforte"
```

Então, quando a função `IncluirUsuario(Usuario usuario)` for chamada, esses atributos já devem ter sido preenchidos.

Uma observação, não tenho certeza, mas acho que você deve colocar essas suas duas respostas junto com a pergunta se elas não forem a solução do seu problema.

Comment: Valeu pessoal! me ajudou muito!

Answer (score 2):

Anderson, sim a instância deste jeito está certo sim. Porém os valores que você vai passar para o método IncluirUsuario vai ser aqueles predefidos na classe. O ideal seria as propriedades dentro da classe serem vazias e quem instanciar preencher os valores. Por exemplo.

```cs
Usuario user = new Userio();
```

e agora você preenche o objeto com as informações do novo usuário a ser criado.

```cs
user.Nome = "Nome do usuário"; 
user.Sobrenome = "Sobrenome do usuário"; 
user.Email = "E-mail"; 
user.Senha = "Senha do usuário"
```

Depois que o objeto estiver preenchido você chama a função IncluirUsuario passando o objetivo que você acabou de criar como parâmetro.

```cs
  IncluirUsuario(user);
```

Comment: Valeu! muito obrigado!

Comment: Por nada ;-)  precisando estamos aí.

Answer (score 0):

@Anderson User777, estas ligado a alguma base de dados?

Se tiveres ligado a base de dados podes trabalhar com linguagem *mysql* e fica tudo bem mais fácil e na minha opinião bem mais bonito e apresentável.

Caso tenhas uma base de dados tenta experimentar conectar-te a base de dados usando :

```
> private string  StringDeConexao = @”Data Source=localhost,1433;Initial
> Catalog=master;User Id=sa;Password=minhasenha;”;
```

Depois de estares conectado a base de dados podes inserir, apagar e alterar os dados.
Pesquisa mais um pouco sobre este método e vê se gostas.